How can I make a dragon/fish/monster fin using geometry nodes? Already have have the spikes, just need the fin!
First time on Stack Exchange, so I hope I'm doing this right! I'm in the middle of modeling a dragon and I would like to have a fin running down her back supported by spikes. I modeled this by hand as a separate mesh from the body so I could use modifiers. Unfortunately, I can't get the dang thing weight painted nicely--even with a data transfer modifier. Therefore, I'd like to make it with geometry nodes! I have the spikes figured out, but I'm struggling to figure out how to connect the spikes with a fin. Here's what I made by hand:

And here's what I have with geometry nodes so far:


In a nutshell, I duplicated the verts running down the dragon's spine and converted them to a curve. I then instanced a cone down that curve and used a float curve to set the Z scale. It deforms beautifully with the armature, but I am am VERY new to geo nodes and I have absolutely no idea how I would go about connecting the spikes with fins. Any ideas?

Could you model a spike and a fin as a single object, then use it instead of a cone to instance with a Object Info node ?
